# Can current `stty -g` settings be saved when also consuming stdin?

Tags: posix, stdin, stty

I'd like to save then restore the current `stty` settings in a script that is also consuming `stdin` however `stty -g` is complaining about it:

> stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

I've tried closing the `stdin` file descriptor and calling `stty` in a subshell with overridden FDs. I can't figure out how to separate `stdin` from `stty -g` and I'd appreciate help or advice.

Note, I'm specifically interested in POSIX compatibility. No Bash/Zsh-isms, please.

Minimal script to reproduce the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Save this so we can restore it later:
saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g)
printf 'stty settings: "%s"\n' "$saved_tty_settings"

# ...Script contents here that do something with stdin.

# Restore settings later
# (not working because the variable above is empty):
stty "$saved_tty_settings"
```

Run with `print 'foo\nbar\n' | ./sttytest` to view the error.

Comment: Maybe `saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g < /dev/tty)`?

Comment: Nope. Did you try it and it works on your machine or are you just guessing?

Comment: @whiteinge, the test command `print 'foo\nbar\n'` won't work; the correct command is `printf 'foo\nbar\n'` .

Comment: And @whiteinge, you are supposed to redirect from `/dev/tty` at the _restoring_ step too, or else `stty` will still bail when restoring states; see my answer.

Comment: I actually tried `echo hello | bash -c 'A=$(stty -g ) ; echo $A'` and `echo hello | bash -c 'A=$(stty -g </dev/tty) ; echo $A'`.  which got me the complaint about ioctl and the correct value in the 2 cases.

Comment: Thanks, @icarus. You are right. I saw the second error and overlooked that the print had picked up the right value. Sorry, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@icarus' comment:

> Maybe `saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g < /dev/tty)`?

is actually pointing to the right direction, but it is not the end of story.

**You will need to apply the same redirection when *restoring* `stty` states too.** Or else, you will still get `Invalid argument` or ioctl failure at the *restoring* stage...

Correct course of action:

```
saved_tty_settings="$(stty -g < /dev/tty)"

# ...do terminal-changing stuff...

stty "$saved_tty_settings" < /dev/tty
```

---

This is the actual script I tested; which I rewrote the whole thing as a classic Bourne shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is sttytest.sh

# This backs up current terminal settings...
STTY_SETTINGS="`stty -g < /dev/tty`"
echo "stty settings: $STTY_SETTINGS"

# This reads from standard input...
while IFS= read LINE
do
    echo "input: $LINE"
done

# This restores terminal settings...
if stty "$STTY_SETTINGS" < /dev/tty
then
    echo "stty settings has been restored sucessfully."
fi
```

The test run:

```
printf 'This\ntext\nis\nfrom\na\nredirection.\n' | sh sttytest.sh
```

The result:

```
stty settings: 2d02:5:4bf:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:1:ff:11:13:1a:ff:12:f:17:16:ff:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
input: This
input: text
input: is
input: from
input: a
input: redirection.
stty settings has been restored sucessfully.
```

Tested using Debian Almquist Shell `dash` 0.5.7, and GNU Coreutils 8.13's `stty`.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for taking the time to step through a full, working explanation!